# Ajax.BeginForm idenfity which button is clicked in OnComplete method

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, ajax.beginform

I have an Ajax.BeginForm with some AjaxOptions.
With the oncomplete I want to check in the javascript function which button of the form has been clicked on.For this I need to send the clicked button as a param along with the OnComplete.

Does anyone know how to do this?

**Ajax beginform:**

```
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm(MvcSettings.SitecoreRouteName, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post", OnFailure = "ShowAjaxError", OnComplete = "ScrollToTop" }))
    {
    }
```

**javascript function:**

```
function ScrollToTop() {
//Todo check button
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 800);
    return false;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm(MvcSettings.SitecoreRouteName, 
    new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post", OnFailure = "ShowAjaxError", OnComplete = "(function(){ScrollToTop(click_button_id);})();" }))
        {
        }

function ScrollToTop(id))
{
$('#'+id)
//now you got button control  do code here
}
```

Comment: What is `click_button_id`? Btw, I don't think you need an IIFE. You could just directly call the function: `OnComplete = "ScrollToTop(click_button_id)"`